# Successive lineTo(x, y) in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, 2d-graphics

When I was doing some graphic designing with JavaScript, I saw this strange behaviour.
When I ran the following code (with proper HTML and JavaScript of course),

```
context.lineTo(100, 100);
context.lineTo(200, 200);
context.stroke();
```

The result was a straight line from (100, 100) to (200, 200), which I wasn't expecting. I expected that nothing would be drawn. I think this would only happen with the following code:

```
context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(100, 100);
context.lineTo(200, 200);
context.stroke();
```

Is my thinking wrong? Why is it happening so? Can anyone explain?

Answer (score 2):

Straight from the [specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#dom-context-2d-lineto) of `lineTo`:

> If the object's path has no subpaths, then ensure there is a subpath for (x, y).

And "ensure that there is a subpath" links to [this bit](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#ensure-there-is-a-subpath):

> When the user agent is to ensure there is a subpath for a coordinate (x, y) on a path, the user agent must check to see if the path has its *need new subpath flag* set. If it does, then the user agent must create a new subpath with the point (x, y) as its first (and only) point, as if the `moveTo()` method had been called, and must then unset the path's *need new subpath flag*.

In short, if you call `lineTo` without an explicit `beginPath`, then a new path is created implicitly, with the given point as its starting point.